# Is it possible to change relation of a field based on a condition?

Tags: odoo, odoo-8, openerp-8

Suppose there is a field 'A' and has an fields declaration say

```
 A:fields.many2one('new.new')
```

and then based on any condition, the same field should get a different relation like

```
if condition:
   A:fields.many2one(old.old)
```

Is it possible?

Comment: your question is if condtion is true then create the many2one fields?

Comment: no at first many2one field is declared with relation(table) 'new.new', then is it possible to change the relation(table) to old.old and re-declare the same many2one field ?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the answer is No. You cannot change at runtime the comodel of a m2o field. It would require to change the Foreign Key and other IR relations which are created when the module is installed/updated.
Maybe you can achieve something similar by creating both

```
A: fields.many2one('old.old')
B: fields.many2one('new.new')
C: fields.Boolean()#condition, eventually computed
```

and then using *A* or *B* depending on your condition.

for the view part:

```
<field name="C" invisible="1"/>
<field name="A" attrs="{'invisible': [('C','=',False)]}"/>
<field name="B" attrs="{'invisible': [('C','=',True)]}"/>
```

C is always invisible, A and B visibility depends on C

Comment: Alessandro, first of all thank you. and yes even i had a doubt on it. Depending on the condition, can we switch the fields that need to be displayed in xml using attrs and invisible ?